# Postgres - Replacing variety of names in a column for a respective unique identifier

Tags: sql, postgresql

The list below refers to persons names before and after marriage. Along the time some of them divorced and married again and/or changed their names.
What I want to do is to take all the names the person had in her lifetime and add a new column with an unique identifier for each person.

This is the actual list called Names:

```
Name_before                  Name_after         
Misti Gulick                 Misti Gulick Thibodeaux            
Faye Leaton                  Faye Leaton Hemby          
Arden Peck                   Arden Peck Mroz            
Carlton Kingsley             Carlton Kingsley Mcelveen          
Dolly Verhey                 Dolly Verhey Irish             
Gaynell Pasquale             Gaynell Pasquale Ayala             
Misti Gulick Thibodeaux      Misti Thibodeaux           
Faye Leaton Hemby            Faye Hemby         
Arden Peck Mroz              Arden Mroz         
Carlton Kingsley Mcelveen    Carlton Mcelveen           
Dolly Verhey Irish           Dolly Irish            
Gaynell Pasquale Ayala       Gaynell Ayala          
Misti Thibodeaux             Misti Trey Thibodeaux          
Faye Hemby                   Faye Barrett Hemby         
Arden Mroz                   Arden Justin Mroz          
Carlton Mcelveen             Carlton Tameka Mcelveen            
Dolly Irish                  Dolly Jeremiah Irish           
Gaynell Ayala                Gaynell Cherry Ayala
```

The ideal list would be something like:

```
Name_before                 Name_after                  Identifier
Misti Gulick                Misti Gulick Thibodeaux     Misti Gulick 
Faye Leaton                 Faye Leaton Hemby           Faye Leaton 
Arden Peck                  Arden Peck Mroz             Arden Peck 
Carlton Kingsley            Carlton Kingsley Mcelveen   Carlton Kingsley 
Dolly Verhey                Dolly Verhey Irish          Dolly Verhey 
Gaynell Pasquale            Gaynell Pasquale Ayala      Gaynell Pasquale 
Misti Gulick Thibodeaux     Misti Thibodeaux            Misti Gulick 
Faye Leaton Hemby           Faye Hemby                  Faye Leaton 
Arden Peck Mroz             Arden Mroz                  Arden Peck 
Carlton Kingsley Mcelveen   Carlton Mcelveen            Carlton Kingsley 
Dolly Verhey Irish          Dolly Irish                 Dolly Verhey 
Gaynell Pasquale Ayala      Gaynell Ayala               Gaynell Pasquale 
Misti Thibodeaux            Misti Trey Thibodeaux       Misti Gulick 
Faye Hemby                  Faye Barrett Hemby          Faye Leaton 
Arden Mroz                  Arden Justin Mroz           Arden Peck 
Carlton Mcelveen            Carlton Tameka Mcelveen     Carlton Kingsley 
Dolly Irish                 Dolly Jeremiah Irish        Dolly Verhey 
Gaynell Ayala               Gaynell Cherry Ayala        Gaynell Pasquale
```

What I have tried to do was to encounter common values from Name_after in Name_before, and do it repeatedly until I got no more matches.
Each time one of these tables are created the amount of names will be reduced.

```
create table name_temp1 as 
   select * 
      from Names 
          where Name_after in (select distinct(Name_before) from Names)
           order by Name_before, Name_after;                    

create table name_temp2 as 
  select * 
     from name_temp1 
       where Name_after in (select distinct(Name_before) from name_temp1) 
           order by Name_before, Name_after;            


create table name_temp3 as 
   select * 
      from name_temp2 
         where Name_after in (select distinct(Name_before) from name_temp2) 
           order by Name_before, Name_after;
```

Then I would use a query with "case" function:

```
select *,case when n3.Name_before=n2.Name_after 
    then case when n2.Name_before=n1.Name_after 
       then n1.Name_after else n.after end end end 
            from Names n,  name_temp1 n1, name_temp2 n2, name_temp3 n3;
```

I know this is not elegant at all and does not have performance. Some of you guys would help me to improve it? Or even other suggestions are welcome!! Thanks,

Comment: Are these change records listed in chronological order ? (There should be an ordering key, or at least a key, IMHO)

Comment: @wildplasser: Actually, if the names are unique, you would not need *any* order. Only one row per person has no leading row, only one has no lagging row. Unambiguous .. But of course, for practical purposes the structure is hardly useful.

Comment: Yes, but my sister has been married to the same person _twice_ (without an intervening marriage, and in both marriages she kept her maiden name ...) In most cases, a bit of implicit order helps to avoid the mismatches.

Answer (score 1):

#### Schema

The target of the whole process should be a **normalized schema**: with a table `person` including a *surrogate primary key* `person_id` (since there is no obvious natural primary key). I suggest you use a [`serial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column for that.
And a table `person_name` with a foreign key to `person`:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE person(
   person_id serial PRIMARY KEY  -- implicit primary key constraint
   -- probably more attributes belonging to the person
 );

CREATE TEMP TABLE person_name(
   person_name_id  serial PRIMARY KEY
  ,person_id       int NOT NULL REFERENCES person(person_id) -- foreign key
  ,name            text NOT NULL
  ,step            int DEFAULT 0
   -- possibly more attributes that belong to the person at this step only
 );
```

`(person_id, name)` cannot be made `UNIQUE`, since the same person can have the same name multiple times over the course of a lifetime.

To distill the data I suppose you use a single query with a [recursive CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html). However, your operation is **bound to be ambiguous** if any of the persons ever shared the same name. You could have nonsensical results or circular dependencies that cannot be resolved without additional information.

The row in `person_name` with `step = 0` would hold your `"Identifier"`.

#### Query

For the sake of this query I am assuming UNIQUE names (or it just can't work.).

```
WITH RECURSIVE p_start AS (
   SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY n.name_before) AS person_id, n.*
   FROM   names n
   LEFT   JOIN names n2 ON n2.name_after = n.name_before
   WHERE  n2.name_after IS NULL
   )
, pers AS (
   SELECT person_id, name_after AS name, 1 AS step
   FROM   p_start

   UNION  ALL
   SELECT p.person_id, n.name_after, p.step + 1
   FROM   pers p
   JOIN   names  n ON n.name_before = p.name
   -- WHERE  p.step < 10 -- If query doesn't finish, stop the infinite recursion
   )
SELECT person_id, name_before AS name, 0 AS step
FROM   p_start
UNION ALL
SELECT person_id, name, step
FROM   pers
ORDER  BY person_id, step
```

[**-> SQLfiddle demo.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9d1b2/2)

#### One-stop-shop

With the above schema in place, you could do **everything** with a single query: fill the new tables and return result:

```
WITH RECURSIVE p_start AS (
   SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY n.name_before) AS person_id, n.*
   FROM   names n
   LEFT   JOIN names n2 ON n2.name_after = n.name_before
   WHERE  n2.name_after IS NULL
   )
, pers AS (
   SELECT person_id, name_after AS name, 1 AS step
   FROM   p_start

   UNION  ALL
   SELECT p.person_id, n.name_after, p.step + 1
   FROM   pers p
   JOIN   names  n ON n.name_before = p.name
   -- WHERE  p.step < 10 -- If query doesn't finish, stop the infinite recursion
   )
, ins_person AS (
   INSERT INTO person(person_id)
   SELECT person_id FROM p_start
   )
INSERT INTO person_name(person_id, name, step)
SELECT person_id, name_before, 0 AS step
FROM   p_start
UNION ALL
SELECT person_id, name, step
FROM   pers
ORDER  BY person_id, step
RETURNING *
```

[**-> SQLfiddle demo.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9d1b2/1)

Finally, init sequence for `person`, so you don't get duplicate key violations later:

```
SELECT setval('person_person_id_seq', (SELECT max(person_id) FROM person))
```

Comment: I had to resort to the implied order of the records to break the potential loops. Yours is cleaner and more sensitive (but mine is less brittle, IMHO)

Comment: @wildplasser: Concerning the schema: I also considered a self join to reference the previous name in `person_name` (like your `parent_id`). Makes later additions or removals easier. Even proposed indices and such (check the change log). But I went with the static numbering with `step` to keep it simple. It's complex enough already.

Comment: The serial while loading is a bit of a hack. BTW: This is the kind of stuff I prefer to do in steps, since some intemediate steps might be needed later. Keeping everything in one table is a way to reduce the mess to a minimum. (SQL is not SAS dammit! ;-) The canon_id in the same table is a pure winner, IMHO. (it automatically implies an FK index on the column, which in most cases (conversions) is enough.

Comment: @wildplasser: The two serials are by the book. `person_name_id` isn't strictly necessary, but I prefer a surrogate pk over a composite pk over three columns. I agree, doing stuff in steps is a sensible approach. In this case, the new tables can just be recreated if anything goes wrong.

Comment: From datamodelling point of view, at least two tables are needed. Plus at least a date or version number for the extra key component (this is, in fact, a history table) . But even if you use a temp/scratch table (which seems a sane way), the added serial can add as a surrogat. Still needs an order in the source table, though...

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

  -- make some data
CREATE TABLE names_org
        ( name_id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , name_org varchar
        , name_new varchar
        );
COPY names_org (name_org,name_new) FROM stdin;
Misti Gulick    Misti Gulick Thibodeaux
Faye Leaton     Faye Leaton Hemby
Arden Peck      Arden Peck Mroz
Carlton Kingsley        Carlton Kingsley Mcelveen
Dolly Verhey    Dolly Verhey Irish
Gaynell Pasquale        Gaynell Pasquale Ayala
Misti Gulick Thibodeaux Misti Thibodeaux
Faye Leaton Hemby       Faye Hemby
Arden Peck Mroz Arden Mroz
Carlton Kingsley Mcelveen       Carlton Mcelveen
Dolly Verhey Irish      Dolly Irish
Gaynell Pasquale Ayala  Gaynell Ayala
Misti Thibodeaux        Misti Trey Thibodeaux
Faye Hemby      Faye Barrett Hemby
Arden Mroz      Arden Justin Mroz
Carlton Mcelveen        Carlton Tameka Mcelveen
Dolly Irish     Dolly Jeremiah Irish
Gaynell Ayala   Gaynell Cherry Ayala
\.

SELECT * FROM names_org;
```

And the changes and updates (in steps, for clarity)

```
  --Add a few self-referencing fields
  --
ALTER TABLE names_org
        -- points to the **first** entry for this person
        ADD COLUMN canon_id INTEGER
                REFERENCES names_org (name_id)
        -- points to the **nearest previous** entry for this person
        , ADD COLUMN parent_id INTEGER
                REFERENCES names_org (name_id)
        ;

        -- Update from **the nearest** previous record; if any
UPDATE names_org dst
SET parent_id = src.name_id
FROM names_org src
   -- src is the previous row for this person
WHERE src.name_new = dst.name_org
AND src.name_id < dst.name_id
   -- The nearest: eliminate the middlemen
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM names_org nx
        WHERE nx.name_new = dst.name_org
        AND nx.name_id < dst.name_id
        AND nx.name_id > src.name_id
        );

   -- Add the final newnames (at the end of the chains) to the table, too.
   -- These are the name strings that only occur in name_new,
   -- but never in name_org
INSERT INTO names_org (name_org, parent_id)
SELECT name_new, name_id
FROM names_org src
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM names_org nx
        WHERE nx.parent_id = src.name_id
        );

        -- Find canonical parent (the head of the chain)
WITH RECURSIVE list AS (
        SELECT name_id AS canon_id
        , name_id AS this_id
        FROM names_org
        WHERE parent_id IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT list.canon_id AS canon_id
                , this.name_id AS this_id
        FROM list
        JOIN names_org this ON this.parent_id = list.this_id
        )
UPDATE names_org this
SET canon_id = list.canon_id
FROM list
WHERE  this.name_id = list.this_id
        ;

   -- Now we can drop the new name and rename the org name
ALTER TABLE names_org DROP COLUMN  name_new ;
ALTER TABLE names_org RENAME COLUMN  name_org TO current_name ;

SELECT * FROM names_org;
```

Results:

```
ALTER TABLE
UPDATE 12
INSERT 0 6
UPDATE 24
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
 name_id |       current_name        | canon_id | parent_id 
---------+---------------------------+----------+-----------
       1 | Misti Gulick              |        1 |          
       2 | Faye Leaton               |        2 |          
       3 | Arden Peck                |        3 |          
       4 | Carlton Kingsley          |        4 |          
       5 | Dolly Verhey              |        5 |          
       6 | Gaynell Pasquale          |        6 |          
       7 | Misti Gulick Thibodeaux   |        1 |         1
       8 | Faye Leaton Hemby         |        2 |         2
       9 | Arden Peck Mroz           |        3 |         3
      10 | Carlton Kingsley Mcelveen |        4 |         4
      11 | Dolly Verhey Irish        |        5 |         5
      12 | Gaynell Pasquale Ayala    |        6 |         6
      13 | Misti Thibodeaux          |        1 |         7
      14 | Faye Hemby                |        2 |         8
      15 | Arden Mroz                |        3 |         9
      16 | Carlton Mcelveen          |        4 |        10
      17 | Dolly Irish               |        5 |        11
      18 | Gaynell Ayala             |        6 |        12
      19 | Misti Trey Thibodeaux     |        1 |        13
      20 | Faye Barrett Hemby        |        2 |        14
      21 | Arden Justin Mroz         |        3 |        15
      22 | Carlton Tameka Mcelveen   |        4 |        16
      23 | Dolly Jeremiah Irish      |        5 |        17
      24 | Gaynell Cherry Ayala      |        6 |        18
(24 rows)
```

Note: this awkward structure unifies the *canonical* name / number (the **start** of the *linked list* ) and the update chain (the **backward linked list**), all combined in one table.

It could be that the update steps can be combined in one statement, but I don't care.
And, as Erwin commented, this process is **very sensitive** to typos, false hits, and mismatches and missing records. In particular, charset glitches can be very painful.

In most cases some manual steps will be needed somewhere in the process.

And, to make things complete: a view to emulate the desired table:

```
CREATE VIEW triple_view AS
SELECT
        COALESCE(prev.current_name ,this.current_name) AS name_before
        , this.current_name AS name_after
        ,  abs.current_name AS identifier
FROM names_org this
JOIN names_org prev ON prev.name_id = this.parent_id
JOIN names_org abs ON abs.name_id = this.canon_id
        ;
SELECT * FROM triple_view;
```

Results from this view:

```
        name_before        |        name_after         |    identifier    
---------------------------+---------------------------+------------------
 Misti Gulick              | Misti Gulick Thibodeaux   | Misti Gulick
 Faye Leaton               | Faye Leaton Hemby         | Faye Leaton
 Arden Peck                | Arden Peck Mroz           | Arden Peck
 Carlton Kingsley          | Carlton Kingsley Mcelveen | Carlton Kingsley
 Dolly Verhey              | Dolly Verhey Irish        | Dolly Verhey
 Gaynell Pasquale          | Gaynell Pasquale Ayala    | Gaynell Pasquale
 Misti Gulick Thibodeaux   | Misti Thibodeaux          | Misti Gulick
 Faye Leaton Hemby         | Faye Hemby                | Faye Leaton
 Arden Peck Mroz           | Arden Mroz                | Arden Peck
 Carlton Kingsley Mcelveen | Carlton Mcelveen          | Carlton Kingsley
 Dolly Verhey Irish        | Dolly Irish               | Dolly Verhey
 Gaynell Pasquale Ayala    | Gaynell Ayala             | Gaynell Pasquale
 Misti Thibodeaux          | Misti Trey Thibodeaux     | Misti Gulick
 Faye Hemby                | Faye Barrett Hemby        | Faye Leaton
 Arden Mroz                | Arden Justin Mroz         | Arden Peck
 Carlton Mcelveen          | Carlton Tameka Mcelveen   | Carlton Kingsley
 Dolly Irish               | Dolly Jeremiah Irish      | Dolly Verhey
 Gaynell Ayala             | Gaynell Cherry Ayala      | Gaynell Pasquale
(18 rows)
```